# Web server not allowing certain HTML tags

Tags: mac, apache-http-server, osx-el-capitan

My web server has an issue with not permitting specific HTML tags (e.g. `href`).

When I try it inserts:

```
<--!Some of your HTML tags were removed due to security reasons--!>
```

Is there a way to bypass this?

Comment: I would contact your web server..

Comment: What are you actually doing?  Where are you putting these tags?

Comment: I am trying to make a youtube src, or any other video/image/website src code, but this program does ***not*** allow it. This is a personal web server, therefore I unable to receive help from admins.